# Zod: Show inferred nested types in IDE

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm using Zod to define schemas and infer the types from the schemas. I prefer to define a new schema whenever I'm nesting objects, like `myObjectSchema` for the `content` property.

```
const myObjectSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  message: z.string(),
});
export type MyObject = z.infer<typeof myObjectSchema>;

const myWrapperSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  content: myObjectSchema,
});
export type MyWrapper = z.infer<typeof myWrapperSchema>;
```

Zod (at least by default) returns a nested structure.

[image]

Is there a way to give Zod the type so it will display the nested type name in i.e. VS Code rather than the type's structure?
(Like this when just using types or interfaces)

[image]

I would like to avoid writing up both the types *and* schemas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

When you infer the type for `myWrapperSchema`, `zod` is looking at the types of all sub fields. So it's basically doing another `z.infer` internally on your `myObjectSchema` and won't see the nice name you've given to that type.

There is a workaround to get the named type into your `MyWrapper` type, but it involves specifying the type for your `myObjectSchema` explicitly:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

interface MyObject {
  id: string;
  message: string;
}
// Here, I'm telling zod that the schema should parse this type
// so there is a named type but it comes at the cost of being
// explicit in the code.
const myObjectSchema: z.ZodType<MyObject> = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  message: z.string()
});

const myWrapperSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  content: myObjectSchema,
});

type MyWrapper = z.infer<typeof myWrapperSchema>;
```

There is a way to get the name to be inferred along with all of the types, but it feels a bit wrong to me:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const myObjectSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  message: z.string()
});
// If I instead use a `type` alias, typescript seems to inline
// the definition, so instead I'm using an interface.
interface MyObject extends z.infer<typeof myObjectSchema> {}
// I make an alias schema as well, to give it the type I just inferred
// above and assign it to itself.
const myObjectAlias: z.ZodType<MyObject> = myObjectSchema;

const myWrapperSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  content: myObjectAlias,
});

// Here the type will show as MyObject
type MyWrapper = z.infer<typeof myWrapperSchema>;
```

Comment: Hey @souperman, thanks for your response. The first suggestion is what I'm trying to avoid as it's just double effort. With big and often nested types though it seems to make sense to use your 2nd suggestion - even though it feels wrong, I agree. I believe that's something Zod could well do by default but maybe they have their reasons not to. Thanks again!