# How can I avoid producing huge declaration files when using zod?

Tags: typescript, zod

I am working on an npm package which provides a number of types and schemas defined using zod.

The package source `index.ts` looks like this:

```
import z from 'zod';

export const schemaA = z.object({ a: z.number() });
export type A = z.infer<typeof schemaA>;

export const schemaB = z.object({ b: schemaA });
export type B = z.infer<typeof schemaB>;
```

When I build it using tsc I get an `index.js`, and a `index.d.ts` that looks like this:

```
import z from 'zod';
export declare const schemaA: z.ZodObject<{
    a: z.ZodNumber;
}, "strip", z.ZodTypeAny, {
    a: number;
}, {
    a: number;
}>;
export type A = z.infer<typeof schemaA>;
export declare const schemaB: z.ZodObject<{
    b: z.ZodObject<{
        a: z.ZodNumber;
    }, "strip", z.ZodTypeAny, {
        a: number;
    }, {
        a: number;
    }>;
}, "strip", z.ZodTypeAny, {
    b: {
        a: number;
    };
}, {
    b: {
        a: number;
    };
}>;
export type B = z.infer<typeof schemaB>;
```

Note that the `A` type is not used within the definition of the `B` type. Instead the type is re-defined within the definition of `B`. In my real package, this kind of duplication means that the `index.d.ts` is many thousands of lines long, whereas the original source is only a few hundred lines.

Is there any way I can avoid this duplication of type definitions in my built declaration files?

Comment: I haven't tried this out, but I figured out a way to get tsserver to report a named type in the code hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74068609/zod-show-inferred-nested-types-in-ide This may work for your use case as well, although it's a bit tortured

Comment: Thank you @Souperman, I have added my own answer based on this idea.

Comment: Glad something similar worked!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution that works for me: I can just use an identity function that I explicitly pass a type parameter into, like this.
Here I'm also taking advantage of a difference in the behaviour between type aliases and interfaces; by using interfaces, I can ensure that the original names are preserved.

```
import z from 'zod';

function reference<T>(schema: z.ZodType<T>) {
  return schema;
}

export const schemaA = z.object({ a: z.number() });
export interface A extends z.infer<typeof schemaA> {}

export const schemaB = z.object({ b: reference<A>(schemaA) });
export interface B extends z.infer<typeof schemaB> {}
```

The resulting `index.d.ts` now references `A` within `B`:

```
import z from 'zod';
export declare const schemaA: z.ZodObject<{
    a: z.ZodNumber;
}, "strip", z.ZodTypeAny, {
    a: number;
}, {
    a: number;
}>;
export interface A extends z.infer<typeof schemaA> {
}
export declare const schemaB: z.ZodObject<{
    b: z.ZodType<A, z.ZodTypeDef, A>;
}, "strip", z.ZodTypeAny, {
    b: A;
}, {
    b: A;
}>;
export interface B extends z.infer<typeof schemaB> {
}
```